# How to delete the first 5900 NULL rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported and excel sheet in SQL Server named DimTime and the date is not in the proper order from 2005 to 2025. So I had to use

```
select * from dbo.DimTime 
order by Date.
```

The results present that the first 5900 rows are NULL and the following are in proper date order starting from 2005 to 2025.

But when I use this simple query, it doesnt work.

```
delete top (5900) from dbo.DimTime
order by Date
```

Thanks!

Beau

Comment: Answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955897/how-to-delete-the-top-1000-rows-from-a-table-using-sql-server-2008

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work.  Do you get an error, or just no rows deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.DimTime
WHERE col IS NULL
```

Presuming all `NULL` rows need to go.