# sql: remove dupliacte rows except one with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, rows

This is my sql query for remove duplicate rows except one with limit

```
DELETE n1 FROM v_news n1, v_news n2 WHERE n1.`id` > n2.`id` AND n1.`url` = n2.`url` ORDER BY n2.`id` LIMIT 100
```

But i get the error like this:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY n2.`id` LIMIT 100' at line 1
```

Where is my wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess in delete query order by and limit is applicable.

Comment: Can remove "order by". But there must be a limit. Because the number of rows is very high.

Comment: usage of orderby keyword with delete operation gives error.

Comment: What you want to do is  not possible using the syntax you want.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: FYI: I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to answer; but in SQL Server you could limit the number of rows deleted this like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956164/361842.  Providing in case that gives any hints.

Comment: @yılmaz Actually, after added the LIMIT to query this error is shown.

Comment: @Jake can you provide sample data and the data you want after running code?

Answer (score 0):

For delete query no need to include `order by` and `limit`. So just remove those two and try like below,

```
DELETE n1 FROM v_news n1, v_news n2 WHERE n1.`id` > n2.`id` AND n1.`url` = n2.`url`
```

Comment: I think the point is @Jake wants to only delete up to 100 rows (not sure why, but presumably there's an underlying logic to this).

Comment: Thanks, I used the limit because the number of rows in my table is millions and the server is unable to complete the request.

Comment: so that u can use delete command within `for` loop. It may will work

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) explains:

> You can specify multiple tables in a `DELETE` statement to delete rows
>   from one or more tables depending on the condition in the `WHERE`
>   clause. You cannot use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` in a multiple-table `DELETE`.

In other words, your `DELETE` references two tables (well, the same table twice), so it is considered a multiple-table delete.  `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are not allowed.

Note:  You should use `JOIN` rather than a comma for specifying the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This approach may work:

```
--use a temp table record the ids of the records you wish to delete
create temporary table if not exists newsIdsToDelete 
(
    Id bigint
    , PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

--populate that table with the IDs from your original query
select n1.`Id` 
into newsIdsToDelete
from v_news n1
inner join v_news n2 
on n2.`id` < n1.`id` 
and n2.`url` = n1.`url` 
order by n2.`id` 
limit 100;

--delete those records where the id's in the list of ids to be deleted
delete v_news 
where `Id` in (
    select `Id` 
    from newsIdsToDelete
);

--clean up the temporary table
drop temporary table if exists newsIdsToDelete;
```

(I don't have MySql, and my knowledge of that DB is pretty ropey, so please test this in a safe place before using).